# Laravel Octane Event Listener not firing

Tags: laravel, swoole, laravel-octane

I'm using laravel sail to run laravel octane on swoole.

I made a change to my EventServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Events\SubscriptionCreated;
use App\Listeners\CreateUserTeam;
use App\Listeners\SendSubscriptionReceipt;
use App\Listeners\UpdateTeamFeatures;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
            CreateUserTeam::class
        ],
        SubscriptionCreated::class => [
            SendSubscriptionReceipt::class,
            UpdateTeamFeatures::class
        ]
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \Log::debug("HERE", $this->listen);
    }
}
```

Here is my listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Models\Team;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class CreateUserTeam
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        \Log::debug("HIT");
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Registered  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Registered $event)
    {
        $user = $event->user;
        $team = Team::create([
            'manager_id' => $user->id,
        ]);
        $team->createAsStripeCustomer();
        $user->update(['team_id' => $team->id]);
    }
}
```

No matter what I try this event listener is not being fired. I've tried clearing the cache, composer dump-autoload, php artisan optimize, reloading octane, stopping octane and starting it again. Even stopping the docker containers and starting them again. Nothing works.

It logs the list of listeners (including the CreateUserTeam listener) and it will fire the Email notification but not the other listener.

If anyone has any insight... please. I am at wits-end

Comment: I didn't run `php artisan event:cache`. That cleared my event cache and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I created same situation with you,

Added my listener like you did:

```
    protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        TestListener::class,
    ],
];
```

Used Laravel's registration test for it:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Auth;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class RegistrationTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_registration_screen_can_be_rendered()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/register');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

    public function test_new_users_can_register()
    {
        $response = $this->post('/register', [
            'name' => 'Test User',
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'password_confirmation' => 'password',
        ]);

        $this->assertAuthenticated();
        $response->assertRedirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}
```

Here is my test listener

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class TestListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        \Log::debug("HIT");
        dump("test");
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  object  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Registered $event)
    {
        $user = $event->user;

        dump($user->id);
    }
}
```

And run my test inside the sail:

[image: sail output]

As you can see it runs handle function inside TestListener.php

Can you remove you other code parts inside handle function and try like this? I think you may have some error in your code